# ios: go back to the previous tabbar item after UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)

Tags: ios, openurl

I have four tabbar items, the first one is the active one after app started. In the second tabbar item I put a view controller in which user can open Settings after touch the button by the code:
    `UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)`

If user change nothing on Settings and go back to the app, the second tabbar is still there. However, if user change something on Settings, Xcode gives the information:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

In this case, if go back to the app, the active tabbar is the first one! This means that the behavior are different on changing the settings or not changing.

What happened when switch back to app after make some changes on Settings? why there is different on different behavior?

Please find the crash log :

```
Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) 
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010054a6d8 
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5 
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5 
Terminating Process: exc handler [0] Triggered by Thread: 0
```

Comment: Obviously in the second instance the app has been terminated, and so it is restarted and you end up on the first tab bar as if it was started for the first time. You just need to find out why the app was terminated. Isn't there anything else in the logs? Check the device logs and not just the app logs.

Comment: This is because your app crashes when you change a setting. When you come back to the app it gets launched all over again that's why you land on your `Initial View Controller` instead of the settings screen.

Comment: Crash logs but I have no idea on it : 
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010054a6d8
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Comment: what you are doing the settings

Comment: I just change the switch to allow the app to access contacts.